# using AST to add an other super-interface

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using AST to modify source code files. Now I stick at a particular problem. I have an interface, lets call it A:

```
public interface A extends A_Super{
    (...)
}
```

Now I want to add an other interface as super interface with AST, lets call it B. The result should look like this:

```
public interface A extends A_Super, B{
    (...)
}
```

I saw that there are lots of 'Decleraton'-classes, i.e. 'MethodDeclaration' or 'SingleVariableDeclaration', but I could not find something like 'ExtendsDeclaration'.

I'd appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 1):

Super interfaces can be found on the type declaration (union of class and interface declarations).

See [TypeDeclaration.superInterfaceTypes()](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/TypeDeclaration.html#superInterfaceTypes%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

here is what you need.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "public interface A extends A_Super{}";
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(source.toCharArray());
    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    AST ast = cu.getAST();
    TypeDeclaration td = (TypeDeclaration) cu.types().get(0);
    td.superInterfaceTypes().add(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName("B")));
    System.out.println(source);
    System.out.println(cu);
}
```